# Pass two parameters to controller, syntax error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a dropdown list. I want to click any item then redirect the view by parameters.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Languages").change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
              window.location.href = "/Survey/SelectLanguage/" + selectedValue+"/id/"+@Model.CampaignGuid;

        });
    });
```

The action method in controller is:

```
 public ActionResult SelectLanguage(string languageName, Guid id)
    {
    }
```

But I found in chrome debugger, there is an error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

If I comment it out the code `window.location.href = "/Survey/SelectLanguage/" + selectedValue+"/id/"+@Model.CampaignGuid;`.

Then the error is gone. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
window.location.href = "/Survey/SelectLanguage/" +
    selectedValue + "/id/" + @Model.CampaignGuid;
```

to

```
window.location.href = "/Survey/SelectLanguage/" + 
    selectedValue + "/id/@Model.CampaignGuid";
```

If `CampaignGuid` is really a `Guid`, then you're writing out `"/id/" + d0164584-bac0-485b-8a84-b7923caa6ee7` to your html, and Chrome's javascript engine doesn't know what `d0164584-bac0-485b-8a84-b7923caa6ee7` is, it needs to be a string.

Comment: @Bigeyes that's a different problem. This should solve your `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` issue.

Comment: I meant that the controller action code is not reached by the url.

Comment: @Bigeyes yep, that's going to be a different issue. You can check what url is being requested and then go from there to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you do not have the url defined and you are using the default route, the default is based on query string. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Languages").change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
              window.location.href = "/Survey/SelectLanguage/@Model.CampaignGuid?languageName=" + selectedValue;
        });
    });
```

By following the default route of asp.net mvc, you can pass an argument named `id` on the url as part of it, then you can use `CampingGuid` as id, and `languageName` you can use query string.

Comment: languageName is the first parameter.

Comment: As I said, `id` is part of the url from default route perspective. Have you tested? What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your url as 
`"/Survey/SelectLanguage?selectedValue=" + selectedValue + "&id=@Model.CampaignGuid"`